# How to make separating lines/borders in a table disappear with CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple HTML table, and I wish to have the separating lines (/ borders?) disappear.
The desired end result is a table that is invisible except for the actual text.

I've tried setting the "border" attribute to 0, didn't help. What is the correct CSS attribute that I should use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
table, tr, td, th {
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem was a duplicate table definition in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Cheers.