# How to make table borders invisible with CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I know this is an oft asked question, but I've tried some of the solutions (such as [How to make separating lines/borders in a table disappear with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124099/how-to-make-separating-lines-borders-in-a-table-disappear-with-css)) but I still can't quite get it.

I have defined via css a table structure with alternating row colors. I'd like the (in particular vertical) borders between teh cells to be invisible and so suppose I either need a zero td border width, or the alternating td border colors to be the same as the background colors.

Example below is what I've tried, in calling a table1 id from html, I get a nice alternating colored row table but with obvious cell borders still - appreciate your help.

```css
#table1 table, tr, td, th {
     border: 0;
}

#table1 tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
     background-color: #A3B9D2; 
}

#table1 tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #E7EDF3;
}
```

and then sample html;

```html
<table id="table1" >
   <tr>
     <td>Test</td><td>(value)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Test2</td><td>(value2)</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm sure you are right - what is the correct way then of defining zero border thickness between column elements? I had tried table, tr, td, th {  border: 0;}
without the #table1 and it didn't work either. I also tried putting border:0; in each of the alternating color sections without luck. Not being up to speed on CSS I was hoping someone would take pity on me ;-)
;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's possible that what you're describing is cellspacing. If that's the case try this in your HTML:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  ...
</table>
```

Cellspacing refers to the space between cells; it's not a border exactly. So, if you're seeing invisible or non-colored spaces between your tds, try adding the cellspacing="0" attribute to your table tag.

Comment: Perfect - Thanks a bunch Tracy. Thanks to everyone else who offered great advice and helped this poor CSS neanderthal ;-)

Comment: Yay. That was my first accepted answer on Stack :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this style:

```
#table1 {border:0px solid transparent;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
#table1 {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `cellspacing="0"` is indeed a sure-fire way to get rid of those pesky lines.  But, personally, I've never liked it - because I have to apply it in each and every table that I create throughout a site, instead of in one neat, centralized spot.

So, I usually go for a solution like elclanrs's in a CSS file.  The cool thing about that solution is that you can remove some of the tags ahead of it to apply lines/borders for just those.

So, in other words, to put a border around a table - without having all of the cells divvied up between lines too - you can do something like this:

```
tr, td, th
{
  border: 0;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`#table1 table, tr, td, th {}` is wrong.

You should do:

```
#table1,
#table1 tr,
#table1 td { border: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks - tried it without luck, borders still present (as in absent color bars rather than solid color borders)

Comment: Try with the cellpadding solutions others are posting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are applying the style to tables **within** table1. The first declaration should actually be:

#table1 { 
        border: 0; 
        }

or

table #table1 { 
        border: 0; 
        }

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? For complete backwards compatibility you still need the `cellspacing="0"` attribute set on the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/RmhxH/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
table,td,tr,th{
  border:0;
}
```